# Cannot Find Symbol Method Error

Tags: java, file, inheritance, methods

I have an assignment from my Java 1 class (I'm a beginner) and the question instructs us to make some code more object-oriented. I've done what I can for the assignment, but one of my files consistently gives me a `Cannot Find Symbol Method` error even though the files are in the same project. I know the methods are there, so what's going on? The error only occurs in `AlienPack`, which doesn't seem to recognize the other files, all of which are in the same project (including `AlienPack`). The `getDamage()` method that's being called in `AlienPack` isn't being found (it's in `SnakeAlien`, `OgreAlien`, etc).

EDIT: The new error for the `getDamage()` methods I'm trying to invoke in `AlienPack` is that the methods still aren't being found. `AlienDriver` can't find `calculateDamage()` either.

Here's the code I've got so far:

Alien:

```
public class Alien {
// instance variables
private String name;
private int health;

// setters
public void setName(String n) {
    name = n; }

public void setHealth(int h) {
    if(h>0&&h<=100) {
        health = h;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid health value!");
        System.exit(0); } }

// getters
public String getName() {
    return name; }

public int getHealth() {
    return health; }

// constructors
public Alien() {
    setName("No name");
    setHealth(100); }

public Alien(String n, int h) {
    setName(n);
    setHealth(h); }

public Alien(Alien anAlien) {
    setName(anAlien.getName());
    setHealth(anAlien.getHealth()); }

public Alien clone() {
    return new Alien(this);
} }
```

SnakeAlien:

```
public class SnakeAlien extends Alien { // new file
// instance variables
private int damage;

// setters
public void setDamage(int d) {
    if(d>0) {
        damage = d;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid damage value!");
        System.exit(0); } }

// getters
public int getDamage() {
    return damage; }

// constructors
public SnakeAlien() {
    super();
    setDamage(0); }

public SnakeAlien(String n, int h, int d) {
    super(n, h);
    setDamage(d); }

public SnakeAlien(SnakeAlien anAlien) {
    super(anAlien);
    setDamage(anAlien.getDamage()); }

public SnakeAlien clone() {
    return new SnakeAlien(this);
} }
```

OgreAlien:

```
public class OgreAlien extends Alien { // new file
// instance variables
private int damage;

// setters
public void setDamage(int d) {
    if(d>0) {
        damage = d;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid damage value!");
        System.exit(0); } } 

// getters
public int getDamage() {
    return damage; }

// constructors
public OgreAlien() {
    super(); 
    setDamage(0); }

public OgreAlien(String n, int h, int d) {
    super(n, h);
    setDamage(d); }

public OgreAlien(OgreAlien anAlien) {
    super(anAlien);
    setDamage(anAlien.getDamage()); }

public OgreAlien clone() {
    return new OgreAlien(this);
} }
```

MarshmallwManAlien:

```
public class MarshmallowManAlien extends Alien { // new file
// instance variables
private int damage;

// setters
public void setDamage(int d) {
    if(d>0) {
        damage = d;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid damage value!");
        System.exit(0); } }

// getters
public int getDamage() {
    return damage; }

// constructors
public MarshmallowManAlien() {
    super();
    setDamage(0); }

public MarshmallowManAlien(String n, int h, int d) {
    super(n, h);
    setDamage(d); }

public MarshmallowManAlien(MarshmallowManAlien anAlien) {
    super(anAlien);
    setDamage(anAlien.getDamage()); }

public MarshmallowManAlien clone() {
    return new MarshmallowManAlien(this);
} }
```

AlienPack:

```
public class AlienPack { // new file, this one isn't recognizing the others
// instance variables
private Alien[] pack;

// setters
public void setPack(Alien[] aliens) {
    pack = new Alien[aliens.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<aliens.length; i++) {
        pack[i]=aliens[i].clone(); } }

// getters
public Alien[] getPack() {
    Alien[] temp = new Alien[pack.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<pack.length; i++) {
        temp[i]=pack[i].clone(); }
    return temp; }

// constructors
public AlienPack() {
    Alien[] nothing = new Alien[1];
    nothing[0]=null;
    setPack(nothing); }

public AlienPack(Alien[] aliens) {
    setPack(aliens);}

// other methods
public int calculateDamage() {
    int damage = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<pack.length; i++) {
        if((new SnakeAlien()).getClass()==pack[i].getClass()) {
            pack[i].getDamage() +=damage;
        } else if((new OgreAlien()).getClass()==pack[i].getClass()) {
            pack[i].getDamage() +=damage;
        } else if((new MarshmallowManAlien()).getClass()==pack[i].getClass()) {
            pack[i].getDamage() +=damage;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid object!");
            System.exit(0); } }     
    return damage; } }
```

AlienDriver:

```
public class AlienDriver { // driver class
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Alien[] group = new Alien[5];
    group[0]= new SnakeAlien("Bobby", 100, 10);
    group[1]= new OgreAlien("Timmy", 100, 6);
    group[2]= new MarshmallowManAlien("Tommy", 100, 1);
    group[3]= new OgreAlien("Ricky", 100, 6);
    group[4]= new SnakeAlien("Mike", 100, 10);

    System.out.println(group.calculateDamage());
```

} }

Comment: Post the **entire** error.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

```
pack[i].getClass().getDamage() ...
```

should be just

```
pack[i].getDamage() ...
```

You seem to be confused about what the `getClass()` method does.  It returns an object which represents the class (i.e. `java.lang.Class`) of another object. It is used for reflection.  To invoke `getDamage()` you would just invoke it directly on `pack[i]` as shown above.

However...

You are attempting to invoke the method `getDamage()` using a reference of type `Alien`, which is a base class of all the concrete alien types.  If you want to do it that way,
`getDamage()` needs to be declared `abstract` in the base class so it can be found and dispatched to the correct subclass when invoking it via an `Alien` reference.

In `Alien`:

```
public abstract class Alien {
    ...
    public abstract int getDamage();
```

An alternative is to cast to the appropriate subclass at each point since you know what it is:

```
((SnakeAlien)pack[i]).getDamage() +=damage;
```

However (again) even that is wrong.  You can't apply `+=` to an "rvalue".  What you need to do here is either:

1. Also declare `setDamage()` abstract in `Alien` and do `pack[i].setDamage(pack[i].getDamage()+damage);`
2. If casting, `((SnakeAlien)pack[i]).setDamage( ((SnakeAlien)pack[i].getDamage()) + damage);`

My Recommendation:

In class Alien:

```
public abstract class Alien {
    ...
    private int damage = 0; // Move damage up to the abstract base class
    public int addToDamage(int n) { this.damage += n; }
    ...
}
```

In your driver, no need to test the class. Invoke the `addToDamage()` method on the `Alien` reference.

Comment: After removing the getClass(), I get an "Unexpected Type" error. In addition, making Alien abstract causes my overridden clone() method to not work. The compiler says the clone() method can't be instantiated.

Comment: Type-casting pack[i] gives me a compiler error of "Unexpected Type", and your second solution makes the compiler say the "+" operator can't be applied to SnakeAlien, int.
My teacher is a stickler for using what we know and only what we know so far in the class, so I can't use abstract.

Comment: OK, with my final recommendation you don't need to make the base class abstract.

Comment: I don't understand. Do I invoke the addToDamage() method where the getDamage() method would be invoked?

Comment: To update the damage value the way you have it now, you have to retrieve the current damage, add the increment, and then re-save the updated damage into the object.  What I'm suggesting is to write a method that does that in a single operation. You hide the complexity in that method, giving the "client" program a cleaner, simpler way to perform the operation.  By putting it in the superclass you only implement it once.

Comment: Unfortunately, AlienPack refuses to acknowledge Alien's existence.

Comment: You are going to have to copy/paste the EXACT error message and identify the specific line in the updated code.

Comment: cannot find symbol method addToDamage(int) AlienPack.java line 32
cannot find symbol method addToDamage(int) AlienPack.java line 34
cannot find symbol method addToDamage(int) AlienPack.java line 36

Like I've said before, AlienPack doesn't seem to recognize the other files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that at least part of your problem is the `getClass()` method. You are expecting it to return an object but it does not. Just call directly to the array.

```
pack[I].getDamage()
```

should work assuming that the correct type of object is stored in pack()